# Fill visible border in StackPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

I put 2 borders inside stackpanel and it should be one border is visible at a time .
I like the visible  border to fill stackpanel

```
<StackPanel>
   <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center"  
           Visibility="{Binding Title_RoleVisibilty, 
                                Converter={StaticResource WriteRoleVisibilityToVisibilityConverter}}">

          <TextBox  Text="{Binding Title}" MaxLength="50"  />

   </Border>
   <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
           Visibility="{Binding Title_RoleVisibilty , 
                                Converter={StaticResource ReadRoleVisibilityToVisibilityConverter}}">

           <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Title }"    />

     </Border>
    </StackPanel>
```

I used stackpanel /Dockpanel and both not filled the desired border filled

Please advice

Comment: Does this all have to be done in XAML?

Comment: You should use another control. For example a grid. I see nothing in your XAML that would need a `StackPanel`

Comment: @Jeff yes it should be in XAML as its WPF application

Comment: @thabet084 - My question was 'Does this ALL have to be done in XAML'.  Depending on the solution, this would be much easier from C#.  WPF supports XAML, but WPF does not require XAML.  Other presentation frameworks can (and do) support XAML as well.  DirectX WinRT apps using C++ allows XAML usage.

Comment: @nvoigt Grid is optimum

Answer (score 0):

The duplication in the borders is adding unnecessary problems. Limit the situation to only one border. Hence you don't have to focus on the border visibility, with only one border and you can the put in styles(?) maybe to focus on the difference needed for the target parameters instead.

For example to solve the problem I have taken your example and added a new binding on MaxLength size which will adjust as needed; for that appears to be the only change required.

```
<StackPanel>

   <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center" >

          <TextBox  Text="{Binding Title}" MaxLength="{Binding MaxSize, Converter=???"  />

   </Border>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: So how to handle showing first border that contains textblock or 2nd border that contains textbox ?

Comment: @thabet084 What is the difference between the borders? If there is one textbox and one border the difference is the data bound to the textbox only. You need to provide more information on why there *is a need* for two borders. Your example does not explain or show the *why*.

Comment: the first border is textbox and other is textblock